# what distribution should my dataset fitted for?

Tags: r, probability, distributions

I have a yield loss data(due to some climate disasters) for each year as below,
I want to fit the dataset with some distribution function such as normal, weibull, gumbel and so on, It seems like a weibull distribution from the histogram plot, but the goodness of fit result show a bad Q-Q plot, and the k-s test reject as a weibull distribution.

It seems that there are some outliers or unexpected higher values in the tail?
should I fit with a discrete probability distribution such as poison?

should I try another distribution function, or my dataset is not suitale for any distribution function, any one can give me some advice?

x=c(0, 0.094, 0.491, 0, 0.029, 0.049, 0.219, 0.068, 0.051, 0.507, 
0.086, 0.028, 0, 0.021, 0, 0.162, 0, 0.096, 0.088, 0.061, 0, 
0.099, 0.113, 0, 0.319, 0.282, 0.016, 1.055, 0.064, 0.062, 0, 
0.719, 0.123, 0, 0, 0.033, 0, 0.062, 0, 0.024, 0, 0, 0.065, 0, 
0.143, 0.048, 0, 0, 0, 0.037, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.025, 0.036, 0)

simple test code in R are as below:

```
require(fitdistrplus)
fit=fitdist(x+0.0001,"weibull")
plot(fit)
gof=gofstat(fit,fitnames="weibull")
gof$kstest
```

[image: performance of weibull fitting]
[image: histogram]

Comment: with 40% $0$-values, it makes no sense to fit a pure-continuous distribution. A zero-inflated model may make sense; it looks to me like an inverse-gamma with zero-inflation might be reasonable (above 0, the distribution is more heavily right skew than a lognormal, so an ordinary gamma won't really work)

Comment: It makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be closer to a gamma distribution (with a lot of 0 values), but the test rejects it.

[image]

The histogram doesn't seem to be representing the data very well, you actually have a very "long tailed distribution" in a "zero inflated" dataset, these topics may help: 
[Linear Model vs Log-Linear vs Negative Binomial](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/284398/linear-model-vs-log-linear-vs-negative-binomial/284486#284486)
and

[Goodness of fit for long-tailed distributed data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184721/goodness-of-fit-for-long-tailed-distributed-data)

Comment: It really seems to be much closer to a gamma distribution.
and there are much information from the links that you provide, my dataset is some what close to that question.
but my purpose is fitting the dataset with a proper statistic distribution, and get the probability for risk analysis, while the mentioned links was devoted to modelling with a lm or glm model.

Comment: I have found another related question dealing with similar problems:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46977242/r-how-to-fit-multiple-distributions)

"The simplest solution is to fit a Bernoulli model to the zero/non-zero data, then a continuous model (lognormal? Gamma?) for the non-zero values. If you want to fit a truncated continuous distribution to the non-zero values, that gets harder …"

[link](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#continuous-data)

but I also do not find any examples or tipps of hoe to achieve that.